# Check wether a button was previosly clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, sapui5

Within a page on my website there are 2 buttons when I click on either of them, they both bring me to 1 Page. I want, when I click on either one, I am brought to page 1. Page 1 checks each button's status so I know which one brought me to page 1.

My first thought was to target the button by ID with:

`this.byId("Button1").getStatus/Value/We`, but it doesn't work, since all of these are `'undefined'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want to put something in the url that tells you how the user got to the page. One button could have a url like:

`http://www.somepage.com/page1?referrer=button1`

and the other button could have a url like:

`http://www.somepage.com/page1?referrer=button2`

Where the value could be the button's id.

Then you can check the `referrer` url parameter in the destination page/route.

Answer (score 1):

You can put something in the URL that tells you the id of the button you clicked on. Like: `https://example.com/page1?buttonId=firstButton`

Here the code to set the URL:

```
button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    window.location = `./page1.html/?buttonId=${event.target.id}`
})
```

And to get the button id:

```
let buttonId;
window.addEventListener("onload", () => {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    buttonId = urlParams.get('buttonId');
    console.log(buttonId)
})
```

Hopefully, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use:- `event.target.id`
in the `onclick` callback function.

You will receive an id of the clicked button.

Example:

```
button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    let clickedButton = event.target 
    // now you can use 
    // clickedButton.id to get the id of the button
})
```